# SDL Max OSX via Homebrew, Makefile not quite working

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, sdl-2

I have installed SDL through homebrew, and it works perfectly with my test program if I enter the following command directly in the terminal:

```
 g++ -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1y hello.cpp hello_main.cpp `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -o hello
```

but unfortunately my attempts to write a makefile (I will definitely need one) have yielded unsuccessful/unexplained results. 
I am following this, but my configuration is different/I am not specifying Cocoa (I don't need to) so I expect that the issues I am encountering are probably due in part to my different requirements:
[Compiling SDL on OS X with makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854444/compiling-sdl-on-os-x-with-makefile?rq=1)
Example:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
SDLFLAGS=`sdl-config --cflags --libs` -framework Cocoa
SOURCES=main.cpp Game.cpp IO.cpp Board.cpp Pieces.cpp Piece.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=tetris

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
 $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(SDLFLAGS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
 rm -rf *.o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

My makefile so far:

```
CXX       = g++
CXXFLAGS  = -c -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1y
SDLFLAGS  = `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
SOURCES   = hello_main.cpp hello.cpp 
OBJECTS   = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECNAME  = hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECNAME)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $ (OBJECTS) $(SDLFLAGS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean :
    -rm -f *.o *.core $(EXECNAME)
```

In my .hpp header file if I `#include <SDL.h>` and run the one-liner command, everything is successful. If I try my makefile above,  cannot be found, but if I then change the directive into `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` the library is discovered. Yet the console output is the following:

```
g++ -c -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1y    hello.cpp   -o hello
```

which is odd.

Running ./hello yields a "permission denied" error, which confirms that the linking and compilation were not successful.
Everyone's system is a little bit different and the questions I've found so far don't help in this case.
I am *very* close to having this working (but then again, how would I start using this in an IDE? I suppose that as long as I can import the fixed makefile or build from the terminal/edit only from the IDE, I am fine.)

What changes in the makefile do I need to make? 
Thank you.

EDIT:

Variation 1:

```
CXX         = g++
CXXFLAGS    = -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1y -c
SDLCFLAGS   = `sdl2-config --cflags`
SDLLIBFLAGS = `sdl2-config --libs`

SOURCES   = hello_main.cpp hello.cpp 
OBJECTS   = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECNAME  = hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECNAME)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $ (OBJECTS) $(SDLLIBFLAGS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SDLCFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean :
    -rm -f *.o *.core $(EXECNAME)
```

Comment: Try it with `\`pkg-config --cflags sdl2 --libs\`` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chatted with a friend and figured what was wrong: a bunch of typos and rule oddities. The following works, for anyone out there who needs a basic makefile:

```
CXX         = g++
CXXFLAGS    = -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1y
#LDFLAGS     = -lSDL2_image
SDLCFLAGS   = $(shell sdl2-config --cflags)
SDLLIBFLAGS = $(shell sdl2-config --libs)

SOURCES   = hello_main.cpp hello.cpp 
OBJECTS   = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECNAME  = hello

all: $(EXECNAME)

$(EXECNAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) $(SDLLIBFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(SDLCFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean :
    -rm -f *.o *.core $(EXECNAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your `sdl2-config` into two - as there are two steps. `sdl2-config --cflags` should go in the compiler step - thats is the `.cpp:.o` line in your example. The linking step should be `sdl2-config --libs` then. The second one seems fine for your case, the additional `--cflags` there does no harm but is not required.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have interpreted your answer correctly. I have edited my question to include what I think that you said, but I still get the console output `g++ -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1y -c    hello.cpp   -o hello` and a `-bash: ./hello: Permission denied` when I try running.

Comment: try `file test` to see that the OS says what kind of file it is. Maybe `chmod u+x test` to make it executable, but seems odd, it should be fine by default.